# Normal Map difference in blender and other soft

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, normals, texture-baking, normal-map

I created a low poly object, and a high poly object (beveled).

[image]

We bake the normal map in Blender. When displayed in Blender it works well, but in other programs (3ds Max / Substance Painter) the low poly mesh and its normal map are displayed poorly (bent faces).

[image]

There is a difference in shading. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the normal map?